# adding a collection to another collection in backbone.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Is it possible to add a collection as the model for a different collection in backbone.js?

I have something like this:

```
var Stroke = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: Point
});

var StrokeCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: Stroke
});
```

When I try to add to my stroke collection:

```
this.strokeCollection.add(new Stroke);
```

I get the following error:

```
TypeError: Object false has no method 'bind'
```

Comment: I think you don't have a valid model here.  Do this to verify it is your model that is busted:

    this.strokeCollection.add(new Backbone.Model);

Answer (score 0):

Even if it is possible, this is not a good idea.  A collection is supposed to represent models not a set of collections.